# Excluir apenas uma frase de um arquivo usando php

Tags: php

Eu quero excluir apenas um frase de todos os lugares em que ela aparece no arquivo, tem alguma função que faça isso, algo que possa me ajudar ou isso é impossível. Tentei, mas só obtive dor de cabeça.

Comment: Que tipo de arquivo é este? TXT?

Comment: não estou usando um formato próprio, é um .apr

Comment: php abre esse tipo de arquivo .apr?

Comment: não só abre como edita

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$caminho = 'caminho/do/arquivo.txt';
$conteudo = file_get_contents($caminho);
file_put_contents($caminho, str_replace('trocar isto', 'por isto', $conteudo));
```

Comment: Apagar é trocar por `''`.